# Is there a way to get the Session object from a static context?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I'm in a C# / ASP.NET project.  I'd like to be able to get a handle on the Session object (HttpSessionState) from a static context.  Is there there any way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    private static new HttpSessionState Session
    {
        get { return HttpContext.Current.Session; }
    }
```

then from another static function you can just refer to it as

```
var myObj = Session[myKey];
```

just like you would from your regular non-static code.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are looking for:-

```
var sess = HttpContext.Current.Session;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `Current` property on `HttpContext` is static, therefore:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session
```

will return the current session from a static context (but you *must* be inside an HTTP context, or `Current` will be null).

Answer (score 1):

[HttpContext.Current.Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session.aspx)