# .NET - Session object is null in static methods

Tags: .net, session, static

I've been trying to implement a static "Current" property, to behave like the HttpContext.Current property, for a few of my classes. Those that rely solely on the context or the request headers behave normally. However, those that depend on the current Session object fail. In those cases, the Session object appears to be null:

```
// THIS WORKS
private static HttpContext Context { get { return HttpContext.Current; } }

// THIS APPEARS TO YIELD NULL
private static HttpSessionState Session { get { return HttpContext.Current.Session; } }

public static EducationalUnit Current
{
    get
    {
        if (Context.Items["EducationalUnit.Current"] == null)
        {
            SetCurrent();
        }
        return (EducationalUnit)Context.Items["EducationalUnit.Current"];
    }

    set
    {
        Context.Items["EducationalUnit.Current"] = value;
    }
} // Current


// I've tried a few things here, to scope out the status of the Session:
private static void SetCurrent()
{
    // shows "null"
    throw new Exception(Session);

    // shows "null"
    throw new Exception(Session.SessionID);

    // also shows "null"
    throw new Exception(HttpContext.Current.Session);

    // shows "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
    throw new Exception(HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID);

    // this, however, properly echos my cookie keys!
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    throw new Exception(js.Serialize(Context.Request.Cookies.Keys.ToString()));

} // SetCurrent()
```

I can't, for the life of me, get a hold of a Session from the SetCurrent() method.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple answer: Something somewhere (not sure what yet) is hitting EducationalUnit.Current before the Session is initialized. Upon adding a conditional to test the Session for null and silently doing nothing, the errors went away and everything worked.

And whatever's hitting EducationalUnit.Current probably doesn't need to be, as it doesn't seem to impact anything ...

Thanks for the feedback!

ADDENDUM: The issue was arising when EducationalUnit.Current was being hit indirectly from a Page property:

```
public partial class client_configuration : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //
    // The problem occurs here:
    //

    private Client c = Client.Current;

    //
    // Client objects refer to EducationalUnit.Current, which attempts
    // to use the Session, which doesn't exist at Page instantiation time.
    // 
    // (The assignment can safely be moved to the Page_Load event.)
    //


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // etc.
    }
}
```

And here's the final (working) EducationalUnit code:

```
private static HttpContext Context { get { return HttpContext.Current; } }
private static HttpSessionState Session { get { return HttpContext.Current.Session; } }


public static EducationalUnit Current
{
    get
    {
        if (Context.Items["EducationalUnit.Current"] == null)
        {
            SetCurrent();
        }
        return (EducationalUnit)Context.Items["EducationalUnit.Current"];
    }

    set
    {
        Context.Items["EducationalUnit.Current"] = value;
    }
} // Current


private static void SetCurrent()
{
    if (Session == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("Session is not initialized!");
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            Guid EUID = new Guid(Session["classroomID"].ToString());
            Current = new EducationalUnit();
            Current.GetDetails(EUID);
        }
        catch
        {
            Current = new EducationalUnit();
        }
    }
} // SetCurrent()
```

Comment: I can update this with the actual, working code tomorrow when I'm back at the office. It's probably what you'd expect. But, I'll post it anyway to verify for everyone that it works as expected! There is, in fact, order in the universe ...

Answer (score 0):

Try `HttpContext.Current.Session`

Comment: and if that doesn't work, pass the session state (or what you need of it) as a parameter to the method

Comment: Tried it. Tried each of the _throw new Exception ..._ lines in the SetCurrent method. The first three all yield null.

Comment: Trying to avoid that, if I can, as it defeats the purpose of providing an easy-access {ClassName}.Current object.

Comment: well, you used HttpContext.*Context*.Session ---
HttpContext.*Current*.Session behaves differently.

Comment: Sorry -- that was a typo introduced in editing the post. I'll correct it above.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that while the HttpContext.Current is a static property, the properties of the object that it returns are not. When you attempt to `private static HttpSessionState Session { get { return HttpContext.Current.Session; } }`, the value is populated on the first reference and thereafter is never updated. Because of that you get the first value the HttpContext.Current.Session held. It held null, which is the absence of a reference, therefore there is no reference to an object for it get and your calls to that property will always return null. All I can really tell you is don't do that.

Furthermore, depending on where in the chain your class gets called, it may not have access to any useful values. Often with static classes, it's simply safer to have the methods take an HttpContext as an argument.

Ok... let's take a look at how Session actually works, under the covers what you have is this:

```
    SessionStateModule  _sessionStateModule;    // if non-null, it means we have a delayed session state item

    public HttpSessionState Session { 
        get {  
            if (_sessionStateModule != null) { 
                lock (this) {  
                    if (_sessionStateModule != null) {  
                        // If it's not null, it means we have a delayed session state item 
                        _sessionStateModule.InitStateStoreItem(true);  
                        _sessionStateModule = null; 
                    } 
                } 
            }  

            return (HttpSessionState)Items[SessionStateUtility.SESSION_KEY];  
        }  
    }

    public IDictionary Items {  
        get {  
            if (_items == null) 
                _items = new Hashtable();  

            return _items; 
        } 
    }
```

Note that it is not static anywhere in it's chain. Web applications follow a specific lifecycle, and a session may not always exist depending on where in the lifecycle you are.... (Out of time. To be continued.)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Why am I then able to access the Request and Response objects from HttpContext.Current?

Comment: Because HttpContext.Current is a static reference to an already existing object. When the object is updated, access to it is still acquired through the reference, therefore it's properties can be accessed normally, by going through that reference which then gives you the updated references/values.

Comment: I understand it's a static reference (a getter, more likely) to an existing object. That doesn't explain why the Session property wouldn't exist. And it doesn't explain why updates to the underlying object break the reference.

I'm also confused as to why this seems to work for other folks, if you're sure it shouldn't:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913821/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-session-object-from-a-static-context

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804256/is-it-safe-to-access-asp-net-session-variables-through-static-properties-of-a-st

Comment: Working on a detailed explanation, but out of time.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you were attempting to say, but the simple answer, though speculative based on the above code, is that the Session is not yet initialized the first time EducationalUnit.Current is being accessed. See my answer below.

Comment: Essentially that is the end result. Did you want me to continue or is what's here enough?

Comment: Nope. No need to go on. You can see the answer I posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807224/net-session-object-is-null-in-static-methods/10808535#10808535

Answer (score 0):

This may be something unrelated to the question asked but may help someone.

I had a `Generic Handler (.ashx)` which was sending output of some user controls which in turn had object datasources which were static methods (in a static class).
These static methods utilized Session Objects. via. `HttpContext.Current.Session`.

however, the `Session` object was null.

On finding further, I found that when you use generic handlers, 
if you want to access session objects, you will have to implement a marker interface `IReadOnlySessionState` on the handler class.
as

```
   public class AjaxHandler : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
        {
         public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
            {
            /* now both context.Session as well as 
    HttpContext.Current.Session will give you session values.
    */
            string str = AjaxHelpers.CustomerInfo();

            }

        }

public static class AjaxHelpers
    {
        public static string CustomerInfo()
        {
           //simplified for brevity.
return HttpContext.Current.Session["test"];

        }
    }
```